# Deny access to specific folder on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I recently migrated a rather large website to Azure.

I know it is not the best practice, but the site is configured to store confidential files within the content folder, which was configured as deny all in IIS.

However, when I try to add a web.config in said folder, Azure just ignores the deny entry when accessing files directly. I have tried different combinations of configs, nothing gives.

```
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
      <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
      </authorization>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<security>
 <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">            
 </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

However, if I upload an invalid web.config to the folder, the site throws an error and nothing is served.

Comment: are you using WIndows Azure Cloud Services? Web Sites? Or Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to move those files off the instance and put them somewhere else (blob storage is a good choice).

What you are doing won't work well at all in a web farm scenario.  Storing files on a single instance for a web site is unworkable for webfarms without some really crazy workarounds.  Although you could technically do this with a single persistent VM, you won't have a very scalable website running on a single instance.

Copy the files into blob storage and replace the direct calls to them with a method that checks security first and then streams and/or generates a SAS signature for the blob in storage.